# existence of a local minimum between to local maximum of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ f $ be continuous on a compact interval $[a, b]$. Suppose that $ f $ has a local
maximum at $x_1$ and a local maximum at $x_2$. Show that there must be a third point between
$x_1$ and $x_2$ where $ f $ has a local minimum.

it is the 4.25 of Apostol

A proof I saw is by contradiction: it says that if no local min then $inf f([x_1,x_2])$ should be $f(x_1)$ or $f(x_2)$, which I thought is wrong. My idea is that use the compact condition that separate $[x_1,x_2]$ into finite open balls and derive the condradiction, is that reasonable?

Comment: Wouldn't it follow from the fact that on $[x_1,x_2]$ $f$ has a minimum?

Comment: @Espace' etale you seem right, this exercise is strange.

Comment: @Espace'etale Mostly, but there's a bit of work needed to handle the case where $f(x_1)$ [or $f(x_2)$] is the minimum.

Comment: I would try using the Extreme Value Theorem, which tells you that $f$ is bounded on $[x_1,x_2]$ and achieves its infimum. Call that point $c$, and then use the definition of local minimum to show $f(c)$ is a local minimum

Comment: @Huiii Perhaps, but it is in fact very useful.